# Handling multiple http responses one by one in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, rxjs

Actually, i have 15 http requests which are send to the API. I want to handle the responses one by one and print a response when the request end.

Service side :

```
    findOneByOne(): Promise<any> {
    const promises = [];

    this.getCardsPath().forEach(element => {
        promises.push(this.getPromises(element));
    });
    return Promise.all(promises)
        .then((res) => res)
        .catch(err => err);
}

getPromises(str: String): Promise<any> {
    return this.requester.obtain({
        restUrl: "/administration/" + str,
        method: RequestMethod.Get
    })
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => this.checkInfoService(res.json()))
        .catch(err => err);
}
```

Component side :

```
display() {
            this.dashboardInfoService.findOneByOne()
            .then((res) => {
                const tab = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    tab.push(res[i][0]);
                }
                this.findPaths(tab);
                this.loadItems(tab);
            })
            .catch((err: any) => {
                if (environment.debugLevel >= 3) console.error(err);
            });
}
```

I'm a begginer in Angular, so i don't really know how to deal with multiple promises.

thanks in advance for your assistance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
findOneByOne() {
  const calls = this.getCardsPath().map(el => this.getPromises(el));
  forkJoin(calls).subscribe(responses => {...});
}
```

`responses` will contain every response, ranging from the first call to the last one : `responses[0]` will be the response for the first element, and so on.

Comment: So i should return something like this :
    Observable.forkJoin(calls).subscribe(responses => {...});

But honestly, i don't really know what should i put between the curly brackets :/

Comment: I think async/await is easter , +1 forkJoin

Comment: @ims16 you should put what you want to do once the requests have been made. For instance, `console.log('Requests made');` would be a good start !

Comment: Ah! it was obvious, thanks for your help, i'll try this :)

Comment: @malbarmawi Promises are fine, but snice RxJs is natively used by Angular and is way more powerful than promises, I think that you should take advantage of it. Personal opinion, but I think it's a good practice to do so !

Comment: @trichetriche Last question please : i have a little problem when i loop on the result. 
`                for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    console.log(i);
                    return res[i].json();
                }`

The code run only for the first value, and i want him to loop 15 times, i know that the problem is the return, but i don't really know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, but yes, simply remove the return and replace it with another console log if you want to see the response

Comment: @trichetriche i want to return the values one by one and catch them in the component. Actually, i'm getting only the first item, but not the others

Comment: Give them to a variable then ! `this.responses = responses`, you can do whatever you want with it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Observable's zip operator where in you can zip all our 15 API call and get the response in an array in the order they were zipped.

More on zip operator: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **async/await**

example of api request

```
export function getData(data) {
  return of(data)
    .pipe(delay(2000))
    .toPromise()
}
```

*component*

```
  async display() {
    let first = await getData('first call');
    console.log(first);

    let second = await getData('second call')
    console.log(second)
  }
```

> You need to mark the methos with `async` in order to use await and convert any observable to `promise` as the example of the api request

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7onrf8)